# how to convert a string to code in Java 8?

Tags: java

For genetic programming (how to use evolution to design software)  I need a method to convert a string (generated by evolution) into Java 8 code. Please, help me.
Other example: For a GUI I have a field: enter your function, say `y = x*x`. It will be read as a string, how can convert it to code to next draw the graph of the function?

Comment: Java doesn't have an `eval`. You'd need to implement an interpreter of some kind. Or a compiler.

Comment: Surely you can write to disk and call javac. You can run the outut, record some metrics and mutate the bytecode from there, right?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a JAVA COMPATIBLE scripting language. Such as [CLOJURE](http://clojure.org), [JYTHON](http://www.jython.org), [JRUBY](http://jruby.org), [GROOVY](http://groovy.codehaus.org) or JavaScript (via [RHINO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino)).

If you are particularly interested in using Java's syntax, then GROOVY should be the way to go.